# Excel VBA - Error: Object Variable or With Block Variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to copy the last cell of a specific column of a sheet to a mastersheet, but it gives me the error of object not defined. I'm  not sure where I got it wrong?

```
If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xls" Then 
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
wsLR = wb.Sheets("financial_report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = wb.Sheets("financial_report").Cells(wsLR,7)
```

Comment: What line generates the error and what is the value of `y` when the error occurs? Hover over y to see its value in a hot-tip bubble.

Comment: Is the workbook already open when this code runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Copy Cell From Workbooks

Check the constants and you're ready to go. It will produce an error if a workbook hasn't got the specified worksheet ("financial_report").

### The Code

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Copies a cell value from all workbooks in a folder to a column
'             in this workbook.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub CopyCellFromWorkbooks()

    ' Source Folder Path
    Const cStrPath As String = _
        "C:\"
    ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStrSource As Variant = "financial_report"
    Const cVntSource As Variant = 7   ' Source Column Letter/Number

    ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStrTarget As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cVntTarget As Variant = 1   ' Target Column Letter/Number

    ' FSO Objects
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object

    Dim objTarget As Worksheet  ' Target Worksheet (ThisWorkbook)
    Dim lngTarget As Long       ' Target Column
    Dim lngSource As Long       ' Source Column

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(cStrPath)

    Set objTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cStrTarget)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "xls" Then
            With Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path).Worksheets(cStrSource)
                With objTarget
                    lngTarget = _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, cVntTarget).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                lngSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cVntSource).End(xlUp).Row
                objTarget.Cells(lngTarget, cVntTarget) _
                        = .Cells(lngSource, cVntSource).Value
                .Parent.Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

### EDIT:

```
Sub CopyCellFromWorkbooksEDIT()

    ' Source Folder Path
    Const cStrPath As String = _
        "C:\"
    ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStrSource As Variant = "financial_report"
    Const cVntSource As Variant = "Y"   ' Source Column Letter/Number

    ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cStrTarget As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const cVntTarget As Variant = 1     ' Target Column Letter/Number

    ' FSO Objects
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object

    Dim objTarget As Worksheet  ' Target Worksheet (ThisWorkbook)
    Dim lngTarget As Long       ' Target Column
    Dim lngSource As Long       ' Source Column

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(cStrPath)

    Set objTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cStrTarget)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "xls" Then
            With Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path).Worksheets(cStrSource)
                With objTarget
                    lngTarget = _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, cVntTarget).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                lngSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cVntSource).End(xlUp).Row
                objTarget.Cells(lngTarget, cVntTarget) _
                        = .Cells(2, 7).Value ' (G2)
                objTarget.Cells(lngTarget, cVntTarget + 1) _
                        = .Cells(lngSource, cVntSource).Value
                .Parent.Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi, VBasic2008, thank you so much for your help. It does the copy function. However, I want to copy the value of specific cell "G2" and the last cell of Column Y into the same row of the master sheet. Is there a way to edit your code so that it can do it?

Comment: Dat Nguyen: In what columns on the mastersheet?

Comment: So G2 will go to A, and the last cell of Column Y to B, and it repeats with other workbooks within the same folder

Comment: There is no error for the code, but now it doesn't return values. When I open the master sheet, it is a blank sheet.

Comment: @Dat Nguyen: The code has to be in the master workbook, and it writes to "Sheet1" or whatever you have for cstrTarget starting from A2 if it is an empty sheet. Is it even opening files (have you changed the folder path (cStrPath))?

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad before for not inputing in the path. After I input in the path, and ran it in the module for the master sheet, it points out the error for the line "With Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path).Worksheets(cStrSource) " with the error saying: "Run-time error 9    Subscript out of range"

Comment: @Dat Nguyen: You probably don't have a sheet with the name cStrSource in the opened workbook. it is the only sentence before the code

Comment: I believe it does. I could take a screenshot of it. The workbook that I'm currently working with has two sheets which are "financial_report" and "Subscription_financial_report". I'll post the picture below

Comment: @Dat Nguyen: I don't need a picture. The code is opening each and every file in the folder, so at least one of them hasn't got the mentioned sheet in it.

Comment: So in the folder, I place the reports with the master sheet. Report workbooks, they all have the "financial_report". Master sheet doesn't. When I open each report, it asks to enable edit first before i can edit it. So does this cause the error for the code?

Comment: @Dat Nguyen: Probably, it works fine on my computer.

Comment: That's the error. I've just run it again with the master sheet outside of the folder, and it works. Thank you so much for your help, VBasic2008. I really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>The following problem actually generates a **1004: Application defined or object defined** error but I am posting this as a cautionary reminder about proper explicit parent references when dealing with a mix of older XLS workbooks and newer XLSX workbooks.</sub>
> <sub>You might want to run this code to see it helps identify the line number of your original error.</sub>

Your external workbook is an XLS with 65536 rows. If ThisWorkbook is an XLSX or similar newer workbook then it has 1048576 rows. The Rows.Count has no explicit parent worksheet and may be trying to look up from the 1048576th row on a worksheet that only has 65536 rows.

```
'at this point, y should be defined as a number greater than zero

If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xls" Then 

    with Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        with .workSheets("financial_report")
            wsLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = .Cells(wsLR, 7).value
        end with
        .close savechanges:=false
    end with

end if
```

I understand that opening the external workbook should make it the ActiveWorkbook and Rows.Count should default to the maximum rows on one of the ActiveWorkbook's worksheets but leaving the Rows.Count parent implicit is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me out. When I tried the code that you provided above, it gives me the same error and the debug points at the line of    With  .Worksheets("financial_report"). I'll add the whole code in the comment below.

Comment: Simply put, that XLS you opened doesn't have a worksheet named 'financial_report'. If it looks like it does, check for leading/trailing spaces or even do a character-by-character comparison against what you typed in code.

Comment: I did a check on it and made sure that it matched. However, it still gives me the same error. I've posted my whole code, could you suggest how I can fix it?

Comment: Double-click the worksheet name tab and tap ctrl+C. On a new blank XLSX worksheet, paste that into A1. Got to your code and copy *financial_report* then paste it into B1. In A2 put `=unicode(mid(A$1, row(1:1), 1))` then fill right to B2 and drag both of them down. Is there any discrepancy in the numbers?

Comment: actually, it says 102. Does that mean there is a difference? I also copy the name of that tab and paste it in the code, but it gives the same error

Comment: Drag A2:B2 down for at least 1 row for every character in 'financial_report'. You'll get errors in both columns when the check is done. 102 is only the *f*.

Comment: It says 105. However, I believe that the error is not the name because I wrote another code with reference to the name as well, and it seems that name was not a problem for that code. So I don't believe that it would be the case here

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1_Query()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:
y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each wbfile In fldr.Files
If fso.GetExtensionName(wbfile.Name) = "xls" Then
With Workbooks.Open(wbfile.Path)
With .Worksheets("financial_report")
wsLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = .Cells(wsLR, 7).Value

End With
.Close savechanges:=False
End With

wb.Close
End if
Next wbfile
End sub
```